# Stored Procedure or a query for this special requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to write a query or a stored procedure in SQL Server to solve this problem - I tried a lot but no chance !

I have this data in a SQL table and I want to make a special operation on it :

```
0   3   1   0   0   0   0   NULL    NULL    35  117461  Mark    CEO     OBAMA   NULL    PARIS   FaceBook    NULL          NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    01/10/2015  Very Good
0   3   1   0   0   0   0   1901    6925    35  117461  Mark    CEO     OBAMA   Med1    PARIS   FaceBook    One2Few 20/10/2015  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL           NULL NULL
0   3   1   0   0   0   0   2135    7835    35  117461  Mark    CEO     OBAMA   Soft1   PARIS   FaceBook    One2Few 27/11/2015  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL           NULL NULL
0   3   1   0   0   0   0   2574    9575    35  117461  Mark    CEO     OBAMA   Med1    PARIS   FaceBook    GroupMe 17/03/2016  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL           NULL NULL
0   3   1   0   0   0   0   2832    1849    35  117461  Mark    CEO     OBAMA   Tech1   PARIS   FaceBook    One2Few 30/05/2016  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL           NULL NULL
```

What I want is to remove the duplication and group those 5 rows into one single row containing the important information:

```
0   3   1   0   0   0   0     Mark          CEO         OBAMA     Med1|Soft1|Tech1     PARIS     FaceBook    01/10/2015    Very Good
```

I explain :

The 7 first columns are count operation and it is always the same in each row.

A concatenation of values Med1|Soft1|Tech1 - when two Values are the same take only one.

Take the comment when it exists here =  "very Good"  - The comment will exist once.

Comment: What are the *names* of these columns...

Comment: C1 to C27 are the names of the columns

Comment: Your columns names are seriously C1...C27????